# Digital Root and Persistence Function

Tags: python, loops

Currently I am trying to make a function that returns the digital root and persistence of an integer, for example: digitalRootAndPersistence(9879) returns [6, 2]. Only built in function I can use is sum, and can use another function I made before called toDigitList which must be implemented into the digitalRoot function.

toDigitList function:

```
def toDigitList(n):
    while n < 10:
      return [n]
    else: 
      return toDigitList(n // 10) + [n % 10]
```

My digitalRoot function: (I do not know what I am doing wrong, Im getting no errors, but also no output.)

```
def digitalRootAndPersistence(n):
    x = (n)   
    count = 0
    while n > 1:
       x = sum(toDigitList(n))
       count += 1
    return (x), count

print(digitalRootAndPersistence(9879))
```

Comment: Check properly, your function is ```digitialRootAndPersistence```, there is an ```a``` in ```digitialRootAndPersistence```.

Comment: Oops, that was just a mistake I made when asking this on stack over flow, I typed the code out instead of copying and pasting because of different computers. The question should now be fixed, but that doesn't seem to be the issue.

Comment: ```while n > 1``` is going in an infinite loop because ```n``` is never decreasing to 1

Comment: So I would need n - 1 after right?

Comment: ```n-=1``` I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of syntactic confusions. The parentheses in these lines of
code are not doing anything.

```
x = (n)   
return (x), count
```

As noted in comments, `n` needs to decrease. Specifically, `n` should become the sum
of the digits. Which means no need for `x`. Also, the break point is `9`, not `1`.

```
def digitalRootAndPersistence(n):
    count = 0
    while n > 9:
       n = sum(toDigitList(n))
       count += 1
    return n, count
```